# Invoke a rails action when a Wordpress form is submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress

How do I invoke an action defined in a controller of my Rails web app when the user submits a form in my Wordpress site?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this isn't some frankenstein Wordpress/Rails app, and what you're talking about are two different applications.

If so, and you don't care about waiting for the action in your Rails controller to complete, you can call it before your form submits (this example is with jQuery):

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({ 
      ... put your GET/POST/whatever options here 
          (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) ... 
    });
    return true;
});
```

Replace `'form'` with an appropriate selector to get the form you care about.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is really quite broad. Rails controller actions can be exposed via routes. The best implementation is to expose an API endpoint that your form can submit to. However there are many things to consider such as security, cross origin requests etc. If you don't know how to get your wordpress form to send a post request (rather than smtp for example) then you can use a service such as formspree, formkeep etc

Here are some links that might help:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
- https://www.codementor.io/kristophmatthews/how-to-configure-your-first-rails-rest-api-du1084ym0
- https://formspree.io
- https://formkeep.com